# MySQL importing updated data into database, with new and updated values

Tags: mysql, database-administration

When you are managing a database and you need to import new data as well as some of the previous data needs to be updated, but not all, what would be best practices to go about this? (ie. May 2022 is new, some products within Jan-April 2022 have updates in value, but not all and the data 2021-back doesn't need to be edited.)

Comment: Load the data into a temporary table. Then use `INSERT INTO real_table SELECT * FROM temp_table ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...` to merge the updates into the table.

Answer (score 0):

This is an UPSERT operation, you have 3 main UPSERT options:

1. UPSERT using INSERT IGNORE
2. UPSERT using REPLACE
3. UPSERT using INSERT with ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE (RECOMMENDED)

Non-destructive, it doesn’t have to drop the duplicate row. Instead, it issues an UPDATE whenever it finds a matching record having the same UNIQUE or PRIMARY KEY value.

i.e.

```
-- Updating duplicate record
INSERT INTO Posts
    (
        postId, postTitle, postPublished
    )
VALUES
    (1, 'MySql Tutorial', '2022-10-08')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    postId = 1, postTitle = 'MySql Tutorial', postPublished = '2022-10-08';
```

Of course you can add a where clause to refine your update.